# Type mismatch error, how to resolve this

Tags: vhdl

Here is my code for a simple ALU that adds and subtracts

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity alu is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
       B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
          funct: in STD_LOGIC;
          op: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
       Result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end alu;

architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin

process (op, funct)
 begin
  case op is
    when "00" => Result <= A+B;
    when "01" => Result <= A-B;
    when others => case funct is 
                        when "0" => Result <= A+B;
                        when "1" => Result <= A-B;
                        when others => null;
    end case;
`end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/alu/alu.vhd" Line 51. Type of funct is     incompatible with type of 0.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/alu/alu.vhd" Line 52. Type of funct is incompatible with type of 1.
ERROR:HDLParsers:163 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/alu/alu.vhd" Line 55. Unexpected symbol read: `.
```

I know it has something to do with type mismatches of 'funct' and 'Result' but I dont know how to resolve it, any ideas?

Comment: '0' is a character literal or a std_logic literal. "0" is a string. These have different types.

Comment: Also, a grave accent character preceding the second`end case;`.  Your code snippet line count doesn't match, we might assume that's line 55. As Brian says should you change those "0" and "1" strings to to character literals '0' and '1' respectively and remove the grave accent character you're code would analyze.  A grave accent is only found in VHDL in IEEE Std 1076-2008, used to signify a tool directive.

Comment: You guys are right, thanks alot for the help, the grave accent got typed by mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This analyzes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--  library ieee;  -- successive library clause has no effect
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity alu is
    port ( 
        a:      in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        b:      in  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        funct:  in  std_logic;
        op:     in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
        result: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)
    );
end alu;

architecture behavioral of alu is
begin

process (op, funct)
 begin
    case op is
        when "00" => 
            result <= a+b;
        when "01" => 
            result <= a-b;
        when others => 
            case funct is 
                when '0' => result <= a+b;  -- "0"
                when '1' => result <= a-b;  -- "1"
                when others => null;
            end case;
    end case; -- `end case;
end process;
end behavioral;
```

Type std_logic has enumerations using character literals and of itself is a scalar, not eligible to have a string assigned to `funct`.  From the std_logic_1164 package declaration:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE std_ulogic IS ( 'U',  -- Uninitialized
                     'X',  -- Forcing  Unknown
                     '0',  -- Forcing  0
                     '1',  -- Forcing  1
                     'Z',  -- High Impedance
                     'W',  -- Weak     Unknown
                     'L',  -- Weak     0
                     'H',  -- Weak     1
                     '-'   -- Don't care
                   );
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SUBTYPE std_logic IS resolved std_ulogic;

-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As mentioned in the comment to your question the grave accent character shouldn't be in front of the second `end case;`.

Comment: @alexhilton: If Davids answer is **the** answer, then you should consider clicking on the check mark beside the answer, since this is proper Stack Overflow behavior (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).  It will also give you +2 rep points (and +15 to the answerer).

Comment: @MortenZilmer Roger that!